# Can I configure Grails to see test classes in my plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, classpath

I have a large grails project split into several 'in place' plugins to keep things nice and modular.  One of my plugins, called 'core services', contains all my domain classes, and also some nice set up work in an abstract test class (adding mock domain instances, etc) that is shared by a number of unit tests.

This is all great for unit tests that also live in the plugin, but I'd like to use that abstract test class to set up mock data in other grails projects' tests that uses that plugin.  It doesn't seem that plugins' test classes are included on the classpath when running tests.  Is there a way I can tell Grails to include them?:

```
//this abstract test class is in the core service plugin's test directory.  My IDE has no problem with this import
import com.myproject.coreservices.service.AbstractGiftInstanceRelatedUnitTest 

//this test class is in the project that uses the plugin
class ClaimGiftControllerTests extends AbstractGiftInstanceRelatedUnitTest { 

.. my tests
}
```

And the output (non important parts removed):

```
| Error Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed:
...../test/unit/com/myproject/ClaimGiftControllerTests.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class com.myproject.coreservices.service.AbstractGiftInstanceRelatedUnitTest
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import com.myproject.coreservices.service.AbstractGiftInstanceRelatedUnitTest
   ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your AbstractGiftInstanceRelatedUnitTest into the src/groovy folder of your plugin, instead of the test folder. That way you can include it in the test cases of the plugin and your other projects.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing that.  I'll give you credit for the answer.  It just feels wrong though :-)